# Azure Data Factory use multiple Azure DevOps repositories

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm working on a project that has:

1. Various parameterised pipelines for multiple Resource Groups
2. Additional pipelines used only in a specific Resource Group

In my mind, each pipeline set has its own repository and then are deployed according to each Resource Group needs.

For instance:

> Resource Group 1, deploy:
>
> Repo 1 (parameter x="rg1")
>
> Repo 2
>
> Repo 3

> Resource Group 2, deploy:
>
> Repo 1 (parameter x="rg2")
>
> Repo 2
>
> Repo 5

- What would be the appropriate way to do this?
- Do I need multiple Data Factories per Resource Group, or can I do it only with 1?
- Can I avoid contributors of the Resource Groups pushing code to the pipelines of type 1? If so, what DevOps structure should I create?

Comment: 1. You could create different repo to save the code and create CI/CD pipeline. 2. We could create multiple Data Factories in the Resource Group. 3. We could configure the pipeline and repo permission to protect the repo and avoid some user change it.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT I think, I'm clear about 1 & 3. However, what is the best practice in 2? Let's say the pipelines in Repo 3 depend on the pipelines in Repo2 in my example. How would the orchestration work there? (i.e. Spin up multiple Data Factories and push or spin up 1 Data Factory and push the repos).
To be honest, I don't think Data Factory has that much flexibility for handling different repos under 1 single resource, but I'm not such an expert on the tool itself.

Comment: [Various parameterised pipelines for multiple Resource Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66703639/azure-data-factory-use-multiple-azure-devops-repositories )

Comment: I don't quite get the question but all of the source code in ADF must reside in one repo. You can't put sets of pipelines in one ADF across repos. Are you talking about deployment pipelines or data pipelines inside ADF?

Comment: The question is old, and I'm no longer working on that problem. In any case, the scenario was as follows: multiple resource groups (i.e., 1 per country/market) with a standard data need (60% of data pipelines in ADF were common (with some parametrization differences), and 40% were country-specific). We solved it with branches per functionality dprod1, dprod2, ... and multiple main_country branches, each with an ADO deployment pipeline. Some conflicts arose when deploying upgrades to some of the dprod branches in some countries, but it was good overall.